# Matrix multiplication in AES' MixColumns step.

Tags: cryptography

In [Advanced Encryption Std](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), say after a `ShiftRow` operation, I want to perform `MixColumns`.

```
      State             MixColumn Matrix             Mixed
┏             ┓       ┏             ┓       ┏             ┓
┃ d4 e0 b8 1e ┃       ┃ 02 03 01 01 ┃       ┃ 04 e0 48 28 ┃ 
┃ bf b4 41 27 ┃       ┃ 01 02 03 01 ┃       ┃ 66 cb f8 06 ┃ 
┃ 5d 52 11 98 ┃       ┃ 01 01 02 03 ┃       ┃ 81 19 d3 26 ┃ 
┃ 30 ae f1 e5 ┃       ┃ 03 01 01 02 ┃       ┃ e5 9a 7a 4c ┃ 
┗             ┛       ┗             ┛       ┗             ┛
```

Example taken from [this flash file](http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/cs381-05/blockciphers/rijndael_ingles2004.swf). I'm puzzled by the description at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#The_MixColumns_step).

The flash told that after `MixColumns`, the 1<sup>st</sup> column of `State` is turned into the 1<sup>st</sup> column of the `Mixed` matrix. How is this so?

First of all, how to multiply a column by a matrix? The shapes don't match, or is there anything special in cryptography? Well, if we transpose the column, I still don't understand: ($\cdot$ means dot product, and here are my **Attempts**)

**# 1**: `[d4 bf 5d 30]`$\cdot$`[02 01 01 03] = d4+d4+bf+5d+30+30+30 = 54 != 04`

**# 2**: `[d4 bf 5d 30]`$\cdot$`[02 01 01 03] = d4+d4+bf+5d+((30<<1) ^ 30) = 14 != 04`

**# 3**: `[d4 bf 5d 30]`$\cdot$`[02 03 01 01] = d4+d4+bf+bf+bf+5d+30 = 72 != 04`

**# 4**: `[d4 bf 5d 30]`$\cdot$`[02 03 01 01] = d4+d4+((bf<<1)^30)^11b+5d+30 = 0F != 04`

What's happening?

Comment: `11b` here means `0x11b`. I'm not sure if it's what Wikipedia means. `^` is `xor`.

Comment: May be, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/how-to-solve-mixcolumns can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the matrix entries are elements of the Galois field $GF(2^8)$, using field poynomial $x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$. There is an excellent Wikipedia article [Rijndael mix columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_mix_columns) which explains this very clearly.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But what is a Galois field, and what's the magic about $+$ being $\oplus$ and that polynomial?

Comment: A Galois field is just another name for a finite field. There is another Wikipedia article, [Finite field arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic), which uses Rijndael's field as an example.